# chrome extension- manifest version 2 _locales issues

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

i'm trying to update my manifest version for my extension but it gave me this problem:

> default locale was specified, but _locales subtree is missing.

this is my manifest.json file, can anyone tell me where is the problem and what can i do?

```
{
  "name": "Selected Text", 
  "version": "0.1", 
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Selected Text and some changes", 
  "default_locale":"en", 
  "browser_action": { 
    "default_title": "S. Text", 
    "default_icon": "online.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "chrome://favicon/", 
    "http://*/*",  
    "https://*/*" 
  ],
  { 
    "matches": ["http://*/*"], 
    "js": ["selection.js"], 
    "run_at": "document_start", 
    "all_frames": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing the required `_locales` directory in your extension root. Since you are specifying a `default_locale`, you need to provide a `_locales` directory, inside of which lie your internationalization options. In your case, you would need to at least have a folder titled `_locales/en`, inside of which you have a `messages.json` file, inside of which you would set your specific parameters (see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/) for more information).

Comment: thank you! but when the manifest version problem is solved my code stop working. do u have any idea y?

Comment: @elianore No prob! In your extension, did you specifically include internationalization options? Meaning have you actually internationalized it by including different translations, etc.? If you don't have any other translations (or don't plan on having them), you can simply remove the `default_locale` parameter and the `_locales` folder (since having one requires having the other) and it should work. If you do want to internationalize, you'll need to to create at least one `messages.json` file (per the link) that contains your translations.

Comment: ok i removed them, thank you for helping me, but my code don't work anymore:S if the json file is version 1 it works but in manifest version 2 it stop working. (the code is to select a word from a text and after one click this word it will be saved in the localStorage )

Comment: @elianore Well let's get it fixed :) Have you viewed the logger to see what errors are getting thrown? I can think of two possible errors - 1.) you are using internationalization in your script (`chrome.i18n.getMessage('...')`), and it fails because it can't find the message [this is unlikely since it works under manifest v1]; or 2.) you are using inline scripts, which are not allowed in v2. Are there any scripts inside of your `popup.html` file? Also, this could be a copy/paste thing, but are your permissions `"https:///"` or `"https://*/*"?

Comment: thank you again! i didn't use internationalization in my script (there is no chrome.i18n.getMessage())
inside the popup.html i hv this script:
>function pasteSelection() { 
>  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
>    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, >function (response) { 
 >     var text = document.getElementById('text');  
 >     text.innerHTML = response.data;}); }); } 
and this is my permissions:
"permissions": [ 
   "tabs", 
   "chrome://favicon/", 
   "http://*/*",  
   "https://*/*" 
 ],
and there is no error just the code don't works:S

Comment: @elianore Okay, I think we're getting close. Try this: create a separate file called `popup.js` and then cut the script code above and paste it into the new document. Then, inside the `<head>` tag in your `popup.html`, add the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>` (make sure that you have removed all of the code for the actual script). This sounds like an inline script issue - in Manifest V2, inline scripts (such as the one you have in `popup.html`) are no longer allowed, so you have to put the script in a different file. Does that make sense?

Comment: this is so logic and i think maybe this is the problem, but i try it and also the code didn't works. should i put anything else in the html file or in the js file (now i have 2 js files)

Comment: @elianore Could you post some of your code? Perhaps the smallest amount that is still functional. That way we can take a look at the actual problem and get it sorted (which we will :) )

Comment: thank uuuuu!!
manifest.json file:
{ 
 "name": "Selected Text", 
 "version": "0.1", 
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "Selected Text and some changes", 
 "browser_action": { 
   "default_title": "S. Text", 
   "default_icon": "online.png", 
   "default_popup": "popup.html"  
 }, 
 "permissions": [ 
   "tabs", 
   "chrome://favicon/", 
   "http://*/*",  
   "https://*/*" 
 ], 
 "content_scripts": [ 
  { 
    "matches": ["http://*/*"], 
    "js": ["selection.js"], 
    "run_at": "document_start", 
    "all_frames": true 
  } 
 ] 
}

Comment: html file:
<html> 
<head> 
<style> 
  body { width: 300px; } 
  textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px;} 
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head> 
<body> 
<textarea id="text"> </textarea> 
<button onclick="pasteSelection(); ">Paste Selection</button> </br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Question</button>
<button onclick="openC()">openCalais</button>
<button onclick="openRet()">Retrieve Calais</button>

Comment: popuup.js (the new file that u told me to create it)

function pasteSelection() { 
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function (response) { 
      var text = document.getElementById('text');  
      text.innerHTML = response.data; 
    }); 
  }); 
} 

function myFunction() { 
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getV"}, function (response) { 
 var x= response.data;
 var name=prompt(x); 
    }); 
  }); 
} 
.
.
.
and another file it's selection.js

Comment: @elianore Can you provide the `selection.js` file as well? I'm going to build it all from my end and debug :0

Comment: ok this is some of selection.js
function test() {
alert("ok ");
}
function loadXMLString(txt) {
    if (window.DOMParser) {     // FireFox, Opera, Chrome, Safari
        parser=new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
    }
    else {                      // Internet Explorer
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
    }
    return xmlDoc;
}

Comment: function loadXMLDoc(docURL) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {        // FireFox, Opera, Chrome, Safari
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {                              // Internet Explorer
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",docURL,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
function loadDoc(docURL) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {        // FireFox, Opera, Chrome, Safari
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

Comment: else {                              // Internet Explorer
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",docURL,false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");//try to force response type
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseText;
}
function displayTranslation(json) {
    var wordreference = JSON.parse(json); //use default "json2.js" parser (just in case JSON object not available)
    var term = ''; var sense = '';

Comment: /* parse JSON response */
   //here the is also some code
function copyText(request, sender, sendResponse) {

 var old = this.document.location.href in localStorage
 //document.write(" old  "+old);
 var b = this.document.location.href ;
 //document.write("    b   "+b);
 var Avalue =localStorage.getItem(b);
 //document.write("     Avalue    "+Avalue);
 
 if (request.method == "getSelection"){
  if(old==true){

Comment: sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
   json = loadDoc("http://api.wordreference.com/0.8/2d882/json/enfr/"+window.getSelection().toString());
   console.info(json);
   localStorage.setItem(this.document.location.href, Avalue +" _- "+ window.getSelection().toString());
  }else{
   sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
   json = loadDoc("http://api.wordreference.com/0.8/2d882/json/enfr/"+window.getSelection().toString());
   console.info(json);
   localStorage.setItem(this.document.location.href, window.getSelection().toString());
   
  }
  
 }

Comment: else if(request.method == "getV"){
  var sWords = localStorage.getItem(b);
  var wordArray=sWords.split("_-");
  var arrLength =wordArray.length;
  for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
   var rand= Math.floor((Math.random()*arrLength)+0);
   var rand1= Math.floor((Math.random()*arrLength)+0);      
   }
   var quest = "quelle est la traduction en francais du mot: "+wordArray[rand] ;
   var quest1 = "quelle est la traduction en francais du mot: "+wordArray[rand1] ;
   
  sendResponse({data: quest});
  }
// else if .... else....

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(copyText);

Comment: @elianore A bit tough to get it all copy/pasted properly (you could try gist.github.com if you want), but there are two issues I see right away: 1.) You don't specify the full URL for the jQuery package. I would actually suggest downloading it as a file and including it in your extension by putting it in the manifest. 2.) The function calls that you have in your `popup.html` are in-line scripts, which are not allowed in manifest 2. Therefore you will want to remove those function calls and instead use `popup.js` to assign those functions to their buttons (you can use jQuery to do so).

Comment: even when calling the buttons in html file **<button onclick="myFunction()">** it is in-line scripts? thank you so much!

Comment: @elianore Yep :) Try moving the assignment of those calls into `popup.js` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the file hierarchy. It should be something like below,

```
- manifest.json
-  _locales    
    -  en 
        - messages.json
    -  es
        - messages.json
    -  ...
        - messages.json
```

### Reference

- [chrome.i18n](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/)
- [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/#overview)
- [messages.json](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/i18n-messages/#overview)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.

Its `"default_locate": "en",`.

But then there is still an error. So just leave it out.

Answer (score -5):

"default_locale":"en",

look at this code and think. you will get solution .